# Defined Route in mvc returns wrong path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have these urls :

```
http://localhost:7708/Product/Search/89737497
http://localhost:7708/Product/Search
```

for this I set `Route` Attribute in Action and Controller like this :

```
[RoutePrefix("Product")]
public partial class ProductController : BaseController
{
    [Route("Search/{categoryCode}")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? categoryCode)
    {
    }
}
```

but I dont send to `Index` Action , send to `GetProductDetail(code)` and returns :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'code' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetProductDetail(Int32)'

and i define this  , in `routeConfig` class, but it does not work :

```
         routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Search",
           url: "Product/Search/{categoryCode}",
           defaults: new { categoryCode = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

I entered those url in the address bar in browser and it returns that error .

I have this to generate url :

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Product.Index(child.Code.ToUrlEncription()))">@child.Name </a>
```

above code generates this url :

```
localhost:7708/Product?categoryCode=121212
```

how can I do this ?

Comment: How do u call Index action from view?

Comment: I enter url in address bar . I have this `<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Product.Index(child.Code.ToUrlEncription()))">@child.Name </a>`

Comment: @Mir let's updated.

Comment: where is your GetProductDetail method or action. Can you show your full code here

Comment: @AnikSaha its in `ProductController ` like this : ` [Route("{code}/{name}")]
        public virtual ActionResult GetProductDetail(int code)
        {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the routes config file you should declare your default action + controller for this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Search",
           url: "Product/Search/{categoryCode}",
           defaults:  controller = "Product", action = "Index", categoryCode = UrlParameter.Optional
         );
```

And for custom routes you should make sure your route config has the following code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //This will map routes from Route attribute.
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // ...
}
```